# Mathematica prints out "List" in For cycle

Tags: scripting

[image: Here is the problem that I cannot seem to solve.]

So I run a For loop and "List" print outs come out of nowhere, how do I get rid of them

Comment: Index zero of an expression is its head. In this case the head is List.

Comment: Also: [don't use `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12). Use `Table`  / `Grid`.

Comment: to expand on the head being `List`: `{a, b, c}` is actually syntactic sugar for `List[a, b, c]`. for any expression `f[a, b, c, ...]`, `f` is called the head. You can take the n'th part `[[n]]` of any expression, not just lists; in the above, `f` is part `0` of `f[a, b, c, ...]`, `a` is part `1`, `b` is part `2`, etc. so `{a, b, c}[[0]]` is `List`, and lists (as datatypes) are therefore 1-indexed in Mathematica.